# Unequivalent Symbol?

Tags: symbols

We have equivalent symbol `\equiv`, but how to write unequivalent like this[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\not\equiv`

Comment: Yes, i've solved my answer. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!